# Count number of commits made by a particular author on a particular repository using GitHub API

Tags: git, github-api

I want to retrieve all repositories a user has contributed and the number of commits made by them in those repositories.

Comment: i can fetch the total number of commits of a particular repo but i can't filter out the commits made by a specified author.

Comment: Please give a [mcve]

Comment: If my username is jamesgolick then i want to count number of commits jamesgolick has made on his repos which i can fetch using: https://api.github.com/users/jamesgolick/repos. If he has a repo called "action_mailer_verp", i want to count the number of commits james has made on "action_mailer_verp".

Comment: [Edit] the question, code isn't going to be readable in comments.